# Angular module that starts from @

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

In one Angular 9 project I noted that some ng modules names starts with @ symbol. It makes module available for other modules using it's path starting from @ like absolute path. It's very handy for @core module, because you don't need to figure out the corresponding relative path when you want to use it in other modules. What is the name of this feature? I want to know more about it.

Comment: Are you talking about the "@" in "@angular/core" ?

Comment: You're probably looking at NPM scoped packages: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scope

Comment: It's called TypeScript path mapping and it's a TypeScript feature, not an Angular feature: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html You don't need the `@`. It's just a convention.

Comment: Seems like it's scoped packages.Thank you.

Comment: _"Seems like it's scoped packages."_ In that case the question is wrong. `@core` is not a scope or a scoped package. `@angular/core` is a scoped package and `@angular` is a scope.

Comment: @core is the module I created

Comment: _"@core is the module I created"_ In that case it's not scoped package but path mapping. Scoped packages are installed with `npm` under `node_modules`.

Comment: Right, it's path mapping, like in link you provided. Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasSablik You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: It's a duplicate. You shouldn't answer duplicates. The other question contains very good answers. You should vote to close.